# Bootstrap different sizes inside same column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a heading that attaches it self to my listview in bootstrap. However the heading does not extend as far as the listview, even though they are in the same column.

I want the title to extend as far as the list, there must be something I'm missing in the CSS.

My Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5" style="margin-left:40px">
    <div class="heading-surround-default-custom">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelTitel" runat="server" CssClass="heading-default-custom" Text="Titel"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </div>
            <div class="list-group">
                <asp:ListView ID="ListViewWebsite" runat="server" DataKeyNames="WebsiteID" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                //List code
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Custom CSS used in code:

```
.heading-default-custom {
    color:#FFF; 
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight:200; 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
}
.heading-surround-default-custom {
    background-color:#FF6600;
}
```

Sorry for mixing style, CSS and poor formatting. A result of repetitive trial and error. Pretty sure I'm missing something really simple.

Comment: What can i see here is margin left 10px; Remove that from your css class.

Comment: margin left only effects text inside the orange. Removing it will not effect the orange

Comment: ah yeah. You have also style="margin-left:40px" and an empty div below that. Give me url and I will look up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's built in `panel` classes to help you here ([docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels)).

Bootply example: http://www.bootply.com/mT5mVxVpOT

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-custom">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>Panel content 1</li>
      <li>Panel content 2</li>
      <li>Panel content 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add your CSS to tweak the colors etc.

```
.panel-custom .panel-heading {
    color:#FFF; 
    font-weight:200; 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color:#FF6600;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-custom .panel-body{
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can I surround a listview with panel and get this effect?

Comment: Yes, if you put the listview in the panel-body I'm pretty sure that would work, but I don't have access to ASP to try it.